# Thinking of writing some Q&As to help move things along

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm a big user of SO, I use it everyday for my job. Then I came across this site and it's made my day! I'm a huge outdoors person.

I know this is in Beta but there doesn't seem like a lot of questions to answer, not on a SO scale anyway. So I was thinking of adding some useful Q&As to the site to try and help things move along a bit.

I've posted one up already.
[How do I tie a figure of 8 knot](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-do-i-tie-a-figure-of-8-knot)

Would this approach generally be welcome within the community?

Comment: we're not so well known as SO (yet!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for it. Just make sure they're high quality questions and answers.

Comment: Will try my best.